# Distinct one column on two tables SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two different tables and I want to use distinct on only one column. I want to get recent records only. what query should I write in SQL Server 2008? I want to use distinct one only CustomerID not any other column.

Table1: `Customer`
Columns: `CustomerID, CustomerName`

Table2: `Order`
Columns: `OrderID, CustomerID, OrderName`

I tried two SQL queries both not working

First query

```
select Distinct on (CustomerID) CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderID, OrderName
from Customer
left join Order on Customer.CustomerID = Order.CustomerID
```

Second query:

```
select Max(Distinct ID) 
    CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderID, OrderName
from
    Customer 
left join 
    Order on Customer.CustomerID = Order.CustomerID
```

Comment: What do you expect for, say, OrderID for a customer who has multiple entries in the original (un-distinct) result?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What are you trying to do here? You mention something about recent records...what defines recent? There is no date column in either of the tables you posted.

Comment: I think he just wants the latest Order per Customer.

Comment: I assume that your customer table has only one record for each customer and that it is when you join to orders you are getting multiple records - one for each order. when you say "recent records" do you mean the last order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the higher OrderID is latest, this should work if I understand your requirement righly:

```
select
    c.CustomerID,
    c.CustomerName,
    o.OrderID,
    o.OrderName
from Customer as c
    inner join (select
                    CustomerID,
                    max(update_date) as max_update_date
                from Customer
                group by CustomerID) as mc
        on mc.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        and mc.max_update_date = c.update_date
    inner join Order as o
        on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    inner join (select
                    CustomerID,
                    max(OrderID) as max_OrderID
                from Order
                group by CustomerID) as m
        on m.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        and m.max_OrderID = o.OrderID
```

Comment: Thanks Ron Smith but it's not working. I am still getting multiple records.

Comment: Do you have duplicate CustomerIDS on your Customer table or duplicate OrderIDs on your Order table?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have duplicate CustomerIDs on Customer table

Comment: Are the CustomerName values different on the duplicate CustomerIDs? If so, how do you choose which name to display?

Comment: I know its very confusion on my database so please leave that. Can you just give a me query example with two tables joins and use distinct on one column. Please?

Comment: I could, but I'm not sure it would return the results you want. I need criteria for choosing which related values to display since there can be many Customer Names for a single CustomerID.

Comment: Okay. I am giving a guestion. 
Table 1: Customer
Columns: CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerPhNum

Table 2: Order
Columns: CustomerID, OrderDate

All customers has multiple phone numbers but I want recent phone number that was updated in the records.

Comment: Is there a created date or version number on the Customer table?

Comment: Ron Smith, I am getting this error. Column 'Customer.CUSTOMERID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks Ron Smith, but still I am having some problems with that. I posted a new question. Can you please reply on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972474/distinct-one-column-in-two-tables-ms-sql-server-2008