# Distinct one column in two tables MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to apply distinct on only CustomerID and get the latest record as I have RecordUpdate_date column in my table1.

I wrote this query but I am missing some rows(records) and getting duplicate records.

Please help me with that.
Thanks

Table1:

```
CustomerID, CustomerName, UpdateDate
```

Table2:

```
CustomerID, DateofBirth
```

My Query:

```
SELECT a.CustomerID
       ,a.CustomerName
       ,a.RecordUpDate_date
       ,b.DateofBirth
    FROM Table1 AS a
    INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT CustomerID
                       ,MAX(RecordUpdate_date) AS max_RecordUpdate_date
                    FROM Table1
                    GROUP BY CustomerID
               ) AS abc
        ON abc.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
           AND abc.max_RecordUpdate_date = a.RecordUpdate_date
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS b
        ON b.CustomerID =  a.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT CustomerID
                       ,MAX(DateofBirth) AS max_dob
                    FROM table2
                    GROUP BY CustomerID
               ) AS m
        ON m.CustomerID = a.Customer
           AND m.max_cus = c.DateofBirth
```

Comment: format your code for the love of god

Comment: What do you want to do?
Give description and a few sample records.
Anyway, the tables do not seem normal!

Comment: Do you just want a distinct list of all customer ids from both tables? You could just do DISTINCT CustomerID from each table, and union the two together.

Comment: CustomerID is a foreign key in table2. So both tables  have same CustomerID numbers.

Comment: Your query has syntax error `ON b.CustomerID = and a.CustomerID` there should be no `AND` in there.

Comment: Why on earth would either of these tables have more than one row for a CustomerID?

Comment: Because CustomerName are updating

Comment: Updating a customer name should update the same row, not create a new row.

Comment: It creates new because have track the date when it was updated

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get only latest record. My personal that I use all the time is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx.

First in CTE we number rows based on the customerid and desc date field. Next you select where `rn =1` this gets only latest record for each customer.

```
;WITH   CTE
          AS (
               SELECT customerID
                   ,customerName
                   ,UpdateDate
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC ) AS rn
                FROM table1 AS a
             )
    SELECT a.customerID
           ,a.CustomerName
           ,a.UpdateDate
           ,b.DateOfBrith
        FROM CTE a
        JOIN table2 AS b
            ON a.customerId = b.CustomerID
        where a.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH    CTE
      AS ( SELECT   CustomerID ,
                    MAX(UpdateDate) max_RecordUpdate_date
           FROM     dbo.Table1
           GROUP BY CustomerID
         ),
    CTE1
      AS ( SELECT   CustomerID ,
                    MAX(DateofBirth) max_dob
           FROM     dbo.Table2
           GROUP BY CustomerID
         )
SELECT  CTE.CustomerID ,
        CustomerName ,
        max_RecordUpdate_date ,
        max_dob ,
        FLOOR(( CAST (max_RecordUpdate_date AS INTEGER)
                - CAST(max_dob AS INTEGER) ) / 365.25) [Age]
FROM    CTE
        INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.CustomerID = CTE.CustomerID
                             AND Table1.UpdateDate = CTE.max_RecordUpdate_date
        LEFT JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.CustomerID = CTE.CustomerID
```

Comment: I cannot use this one because I have some calculations in my select statement. Select a.CustomerID ,a.CustomerName ,a.RecordUpDate_date ,b.DateofBirth, FLOOR((CAST (a.RecordUpdate_date AS INTEGER) - CAST(c.DATEOFBIRTH AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age ... Can you add this calculation in solution?

Comment: @SQL why isn't that information in the question? Is there anything else crucial to your solution that you haven't bothered to tell anyone?

Comment: That was the only one. Sorry for not mentioning in the question. I just got that request now.

Comment: I have added the calculation, but you have to take care of nulls from left join, if any.

Comment: Thank a lot  Njnoorie, it works. But I am missing records because I looked on my database I should get more results than getting now.

Comment: The sql will return all the distinct customer ids from table table1. It is not possible that the sql will omit few records. Please check your data, there might be some discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.CustomerId, a.CustomerName, a.UpdateDate, b.DateofBirth
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerId, MAX(UpdateDate) as UDate
            FROM Table1
            GROUP BY CustomerId
            )  maxdate  ON a.CustomerId = maxdate.CustomerId
                        AND a.UpdateDate = maxdate.UDate
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
```

Use SELECT DISTINCT if you have multiple records for a customerid and updatedate.

Comment: Getting this error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'inner'.